# UIButton setTitleColor:forState: question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

Why does the following code work...

```
[signInBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[signInBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

while this does not?

```
[signInBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Comment: Wow, that does seem strange to not work. +1

Comment: Notice how the method name only mentions a singular `state:` not `states:`.

Comment: @Jasarien they shouldn't use bitmasks then

Comment: @Jasarien: Fair point...

Comment: @bioffe: They use bitmasks so the `state` property can represent multiple states. Which again begs the question why `state` and not `states` too though :P

Comment: Perhaps a good question for the Apple developer boards. :-)

Comment: I just encountered this bug and reported it to Apple. Suggest you do it too so that Apple is more likely to fix it.

Comment: Thank god I found this post! I would never have suspected a fail like this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but these answers aren't correct.

When you set each separately you are saying the `state` property should be `UIControlStateHighlighted` OR `UIControlStateDisabled` but NOT both

When you bitwise or them together you are stating they must BOTH be set in the `state` property. Meaning  `UIControlStateHighlighted` AND `UIControlStateDisabled` are set in the `state` property.

The example code below perfectly illustrates my point. If you disagree run it for yourself.

```
[button setTitle:@"highlighted and selected" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected];
[button setTitle:@"Highlighted only" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setTitle:@"Selected only" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button setTitle:@"Normal" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

NSLog(@"Normal title: %@", [[button titleLabel] text]); // prints title: Normal

[button setSelected:YES];

NSLog(@"Selected title: %@", [[button titleLabel] text]); // prints title: Selected only 

[button setSelected:NO];
[button setHighlighted:YES];

NSLog(@"highlighted title: %@", [[button titleLabel] text]); // prints title: Highlighted only

[button setSelected:YES];

NSLog(@"highlighted and selected title: %@", [[button titleLabel] text]); // prints title: highlighted and selected
```

Comment: Totally disagree. You have a mask where each bit represents a state. If set separately it uses bitwise OR. We can always retrieve mask value to verify that. Why can't it be set in one shot, beyond my comprehension.

Comment: How do you retrieve the mask value to verify that it bitwise OR'ed the control state for the two above calls?

Comment: @bioffer: You are wrong, Patrick is right. Each time you call `setTitle:forState:` it sets an additional title inside the button and assigns it to that particular mask combination. When a mask combination doesn't exist, it falls back to the title set for the UIControlStateNormal mask. For example, if you comment the first line in Patrick's example, the last `NSLog()` will print `"highlighted and selected title: normal"`. This is because you did not set a title for when the button is both highlighted and selected.

Comment: I agree with Patrick. If you `|` them together, you are saying to set a color when the button is in both states at the same time, not if the state is either or. Think of bitmasks like booleans. You are checking if both flags are true by using the `|` operator.

Answer (score 2):

Because the setTitleColor:forState: method can only accept a known UIControlState and you're ORing two UIControlState values together.

<strike>Each UIControlState is (at a low level) most likely a simple integer constant.</strike>

**Update:**

It's a bitmask, which makes it a rather more odd that it doesn't work, but my point still stands. (It is leaning alarmingly to one side and wobbling dangerously though.)

Comment: [`UIControlState` is a bitmask.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlState)

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlState

Comment: My bad. Quite curious that it doesn't work. (They presumably aren't checking what bits are set, just comparing against the known constants.)

Comment: Despite being bitmasks and that they should bit-or together, it never works for me, either. I have 4 separate lines each time, disappointingly.

Comment: @middaparka: That's a valid guess.

Comment: @BoltClock Guess it's just another "one of those things" :-)

Comment: You were right the first time (sort of..). The button will never be in both the highlighted and disabled state at the same time, which is why it doesn't work. `UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateDisabled` check that the button is in both of those states at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

It could be a bug. Try changing bitmask with unexpected value like `UIControlStateHighlighted` & `UIControlStateDisabled`, and it make all the state color the same.