# UIButton text color & states

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a view with buttons which text color is defined in a property file.

In order to set the text color of these buttons through the controller of my view i bound them from my nib to a "IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray" in my view controller.

So i tried 2 things to set the color of my buttons :

1/

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [myButtons setValue:[UIColor redColor] forKeyPath:@"titleLabel.textColor"];
}
```

2/

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    for(UIButton *b in myButtons) {
        [b setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:(UIControlStateNormal | UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateApplication | UIControlStateReserved | UIControlStateHighlighted)];
    }
}
```

Here is the thing :

1/ when my view is loaded my buttons text color is red but when i touch one it turns to the default colors.

2/ the buttons stay to the default color.

I want them to stay with the color i defined.
Is there something wrong in the way i do that ?

Comment: this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370466/uibutton-settitleforstate-question

Comment: I replaced "|" by "&" in the state mask parameters and it works. Thanks !