# Better Way to Set Button Title for 2 States

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, xcode5

This is how I am doing it now

```
[self.distanceFilter setTitle:strValueForDistanceFilter forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.distanceFilter setTitle:strValueForDistanceFilter forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

What would be a better way to do so, so that the title change for bot UIControlStateNormal and even if the button is selected

What I've tried:

```
[self.distanceFilter setTitle:strValueForDistanceFilter forState:UIControlStateNormal | UIControlStateSelected];
```

The thing is UIControlStateNormal is 0. So UIControlStateNormal | UIControlStateSelected is just UIControlStateSelected. That means the title don't change when button is not selected.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370466/uibutton-settitleforstate-question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that sounds like a perfect job for a category on `UIButton`:

```
- (void)setTitleForAllStates:(NSString *)title
{
    for (UIControlState i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        [self setTitle:title forState:i];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `|` to perform a bitwsie OR, Like so:

```
[self.distanceFilter setTitle:strValueForDistanceFilter forState:UIControlStateNormal | UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: To be precise, it's a "bitwise OR".

Comment: Actually won't work UIControlStateNormal | UIControlStateSelected will simply become UIControlStateSelected and that won't work when button is normal.

Answer (score 1):

Some other way,

```
#define UIControlStateAll UIControlStateNormal | UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted

[self.distanceFilter setTitle:strValueForDistanceFilter forState:UIControlStateAll];
```

Comment: Won't work. You should have used `|` instead of `&`.