# How to set same title color of UIButton for different states?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uicolor

I have created an instance of `UIButton` and want to set the title color for `Normal` state, `Selected` state and `Highlighted` state. And I am doing so as-

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState: UIControlStateSelected];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

with above code when I build and run the app the text is shown up with red color as intended.

But when I set the title color of button for all states in one statement as -

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal | UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

build and run the app...

problem

the text on button is shown up in white color.

Is this(the above statement) not the correct way to set the title color of `UIButton` and does I need to set the title color of `UIButton` in three different statements?

Any suggestions/ help is appreciated!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: From your try: `In general, if a property is not specified for a state, the default is to use the UIControlStateNormal value. If the UIControlStateNormal value is not set, then the property defaults to a system value. Therefore, at a minimum, you should set the value for the normal state.`

Comment: Your question seems like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370466/uibutton-settitleforstate-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand how bit masks work. Merlin has pointed in the right direction, but he hasn't actually given an explanation.

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIControlState) {
    UIControlStateNormal       = 0,
    UIControlStateHighlighted  = 1 << 0,                  // used when UIControl isHighlighted is set
    UIControlStateDisabled     = 1 << 1,
    UIControlStateSelected     = 1 << 2,                  // flag usable by app (see below)
    UIControlStateApplication  = 0x00FF0000,              // additional flags available for application use
    UIControlStateReserved     = 0xFF000000               // flags reserved for internal framework use
};
```

`UIControlStateNormal` is a default state. It does not really use bit-mask. States `UIControlStateHighlighted`, `UIControlStateDisabled`, `UIControlStateSelected`  in the `ENUM` are using bit-masks, so can be used in the way you have done in your OP.

For example, take a look at the `ENUM` for `UIUserNotificationType`:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIUserNotificationType) {
    UIUserNotificationTypeNone    = 0,      // the application may not present any UI upon a notification being received
    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge   = 1 << 0, // the application may badge its icon upon a notification being received
    UIUserNotificationTypeSound   = 1 << 1, // the application may play a sound upon a notification being received
    UIUserNotificationTypeAlert   = 1 << 2, // the application may display an alert upon a notification being received
} NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
```

`UIUserNotificationTypeNone` is not a bit mask. You don't register for notifications of types Sound, badge, and none at the same time. None, and others have to be exclusive (XOR of sorts).

Same applies to `UIControlState`. `UIControlStateNormal` must not be used with other states. You can use the bit-mask values in any combination, but if you introduce even a single non-bit-mask value, the results will be something you won't expect. For your specific case, Merlin has given the exact result of using a non-bit-mask value with other bit-masks.

In a nutshell, if you use `UIControlStateNormal`, set the `tintColor` along with it. Otherwise, use the bit-masked values only.

Answer (score 2):

Just set titleColor for normal state

```
 [button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 button.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: thanks, but why can't I set the red color for all states in a single statement?

Comment: setTitleColor does not evaluate your or condition ,thats why you are facing problem

Comment: but normally properties are set in this way

Comment: also why to set tint color, what purpose it will serve?

Comment: what about setting color for other states?

Comment: [button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor yellowColor] forState: UIControlStateSelected];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

Comment: what purpose button.tintColor will serve?

Comment: default tint color is blue. if you want to set same color for different states then just set tintColor same as Normal state color . other wise set it nil

Answer (score 2):

UIControlState is defined as

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIControlState) {
UIControlStateNormal       = 0,
UIControlStateHighlighted  = 1 << 0,                  // used when UIControl isHighlighted is set
UIControlStateDisabled     = 1 << 1,
UIControlStateSelected     = 1 << 2,                  // flag usable by app (see below)
UIControlStateApplication  = 0x00FF0000,              // additional flags available for application use
UIControlStateReserved     = 0xFF000000               // flags reserved for internal framework use
};
```

When you write

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal | UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

it really means that you are setting red color for state 0x00000101. Button will never be in this state because it is undefined. So the behavior is undefined too.

Comment: You pointed in the right direction. It would have been much better if you left a detailed explanation, since not a lot of people understand how bit-masks work. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do these with storyboard also.

[image: button properties]

From state config attribute , you can select any state you want and set different properties accordingly.